# playframework-2.3 Akka-Async interaction porting?

Tags: java, akka, porting, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have some old playframework 2.2 java webservice that interacts with akka, and now I should port them to playframework 2.3.

However, async has been deprecated and even after reading the doc about the async porting (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync) I wasn't able to understand how to apply it to my case (code below):

- I must make the await for a timeout/akka server reply before starting the construction of my reply (ok()), otherwise I will block the thread.
- I should make the actorselection async too.
- I should make the akka server reply parsing/reply construction async too

I looked around and I wasn't able to find an example of such interactions, even in typesafe templates.

How could I do that?

```
/* playframework 2.2 code */

public class Resolve extends Controller {

    private final static String RESOLVER_ACTOR = play.Play.application().configuration().getString("actor.resolve");

    @CorsRest
    @VerboseRest
    @RequireAuthentication
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result getJsonTree() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        ProtoBufMessages.ResolveRequest msg;
        ResolveRequestInput input;

        try {
            input = new ResolveRequestInput(json);
        } catch (rest.exceptions.MalformedInputException mie) {
            return badRequest(mie.getMessage());
        }

        msg = ((ProtoBufMessages.ResolveRequest)input.getMessage());

        ActorSelection resolver = Akka.system().actorSelection(RESOLVER_ACTOR);


        Timeout tim = new Timeout(Duration.create(4, "seconds"));

        Future<Object> fut = Patterns.ask(resolver, input.getMessage(), tim);

        return async (
                F.Promise.wrap(fut).map(
                        new F.Function<Object, Result>() {
                            public Result apply(Object response) {
                                ProtoBufMessages.ResolveReply rsp = ((ProtoBufMessages.ResolveReply)response);
                                ResolveOutput output = new ResolveOutput(rsp);
                                return ok(output.getJsonReply());
                            }
                        }
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with the code below

```
public class Resolve extends Controller {

    private final static String RESOLVER_ACTOR = play.Play.application().configuration().getString("actor.resolve");
    private final static BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply request_error = BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply.newBuilder()
        .setReturnCode(BResults.REQUEST_FAILED)
        .build();

    @CorsRest
    @VerboseRest
    @RequireAuthentication
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)

public static Result resolve_map() {

    final ResolveRequestInput input;
    final F.Promise<ActorSelection> selected_target;
    final F.Promise<Future<Object>> backend_request;
    final F.Promise<BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply> backend_reply;
    final F.Promise<ObjectNode> decode_json;
    final F.Promise<Result> ok_result;
    final JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    try {
        input = new ResolveRequestInput(json);
    } catch (rest.exceptions.MalformedInputException mie) {
        return badRequest(mie.getMessage());
    }

    selected_target = F.Promise.promise(
      new F.Function0<ActorSelection>() {
          @Override
          public ActorSelection apply() throws Throwable {
              return Akka.system().actorSelection(RESOLVER_ACTOR);    
          }
      }      
    );

    backend_request =
            selected_target.map(
                    new F.Function<ActorSelection, Future<Object>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Future<Object> apply(ActorSelection actorSelection) throws Throwable {
                            return Patterns.ask(actorSelection, input.getMessage(),new Timeout(Duration.create(4, "seconds")));
                        }
                    }
            );

    backend_reply = backend_request.map(

            new F.Function<Future<Object>, BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply>() {
                @Override
                public BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply apply(Future<Object> akka_reply) throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        return (BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply) Await.result(akka_reply, Duration.create(4, "seconds"));
                    }catch(Exception error)
                    {
                        return request_error;
                    }    
                }
            }
    );

    decode_json = backend_reply.map(

            new F.Function<BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply, ObjectNode>() {
                @Override
                public ObjectNode apply(BrainProtoMessages.ResolveReply response) throws Throwable {
                    return new ResolveOutput(response).getJsonReply();
                }
            }
        );

    ok_result = decode_json.map(
            new F.Function<ObjectNode, Result>() {
                @Override
                public Result apply(ObjectNode reply) {
                    return ok(reply);
                }
            }
    );

    try {
        return ok_result.get(8000);
    }catch(Exception error)
    {
        return internalServerError();
    }

}
```

}